# Custom function in Google Script doesn't work when downloaded as Microsoft Excel

Tags: javascript, excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am very new to JS. I wrote a simple function in Google Script. It worked well in Google Sheets. But, give an error when the sheet is downloaded as Microsoft Excel. My function if as below.

```
function test(input){
  var str = "";
  for(i=0; i<input.length; i++){
    for(j=0; j<input[i].length; j++){
      var char0 = input[i][j].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
      var sub = input[i][j].substr(1,input[i][j].length);
      str = str.concat(char0,sub,",");               
    }
  }
  return str;
}
```

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't have had expectation that it should work.

Answer (score 3):

Newer version of Microsoft Excel supports javascript. See below link

[Create custom functions in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-overview)

Per this link, you need to have below versions to be able to utilize this capability.

> Note that Excel custom functions are available on the following platforms.
>
> - Office on Windows (version 1904 or later, connected to Office 365 subscription)
> - Office on Mac (version 16.24 or later, connected to Office 365 subscription)
> - Office on the web
> - Excel custom functions are currently not supported on iPad or in one-time purchase versions of Office 2019 or earlier.

Alternatively, you can use VBA to build a user defined function which will achieve similar result if you want to continue with Excel which is having version other than listed above.

An equivalent VBA UDF will look like below which can be used in cell in a fairly similar manner i.e. `=UCaseString(K2)` where data is in cell `K2`

```
Function UCaseString(strInput As String) As String
Dim i As Long
UCaseString = ""
For i = 1 To Len(strInput)
    UCaseString = UCaseString & Mid(UCase(strInput), i, 1) & ","
Next i
End Function
```

Comment: I thought excel supported JavaScript specifically [tag:office-js].

Comment: @TheMaster You are correct. Implementation is not possible in all versions of Excel. I have edited my answer to reflect relevant details. Thank you for correcting.